# ПиццерИя или пиццЕрия?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение в слове "пиццерия"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пиццерия пришло к нам с ударением на Е, но в народе произносили с ударением на И, как кулинарИя, где разговорное ударение вытеснило книжное( кулинАрия - устаревшее). По аналогии стали произносить слово пиццерИя. Словари зафиксировали оба варианта, но норма - пиццерИя, пиццЕрия-допустимый вариант, т.е. разговорный. 
Источник - словарь "Русская речь в эфире"

Comment: Интересно откуда оно пришло с ударением на Е, если по итальянски ударение на И. https://forvo.com/search/pizzeria/it/

Answer (score 2):

ПиццЕрия и пиццерИя в большинстве словарей отмечены как равноправные

Comment: Из "раноправщиков" знаю только Лопатина.
Везде - пиццЕрия.

Comment: Считаю, что правильным  является вариант произношения,в которым слово пришло в русский язык, бесконечные замены слов на разговорные варианты являются уступкой безграмотности и ведут к нарушению   норм  произношения в русском языке.

Comment: Кроме Лопатина - у Ожегова (Шведовой), Ефремовой. Это, конечно, толковые словари. Но все же...Словарь ударений действительно дает один вариант.

Comment: А эти товарищи различают допустимый вариант и равноправный?

Comment: Бесконечные замены слов на разговорные варианты – это уступка не безграмотности, а естественным процессам внутри языка. Да и о каких нарушениях нормы можно говорить, когда речь идет об иностранном слове? Оно ассимилируется русским языком, подстраивается фонетически, ритмически.