# Пиццерия: откуда пошло смещение ударения?

Tags: орфоэпия

Слово *пиццерия* имеет такое морфемное строение:

```
пицц/ери/я
```

В русском языке мне удалось найти ещё одно слово со сходным составом:

```
жандарм/ери/я
```

При этом в речи наблюдается употребление слова с ударением, не соответствующим словарной норме:

```
пиццерИя вместо пиццЕрия
```

Обычно такие процессы в языке происходят по аналогии, но здесь мне не удаётся найти сколько-нибудь убедительной системы. Так в языке встречаются оба варианта постановки ударения:

```
бижутЕрия
артиллЕрия
```

Но:

```
дизентерИя
периферИя
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: [Для справки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%98%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D0%95%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Я никогда не слышал варианта "пиццЕрия" и даже не знал, что так в словаре зафиксировано - видимо, так говорили в городе, из которого управляют орфографией :). Объяснение ударению на последнем "и" простое: так в итальянском языке. Если что-то в некоторых местах изменилось, то от того, что люди стали больше ездить.

Comment: @Alex_ander Тоже не слышал, но так зафиксировано во всех орфоэпических словарях, где я посмотрел. Интересная аномалия.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ПиццерИя или пиццЕрия?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%98%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%86%d0%95%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, дело тут в том, что пицца традиционно ассоциируется с Италией, а в итальянском языке ударение (почти всегда) на предпоследнем слоге, и, соответственно, в слове pizzeria итальянцы ставят ударение на i. Возможно, слово прямо с таким ударением и пришло из итальянского, или изменилось в головах людей в процессе.